# How to get absolute file names, to use with `cd`?

Tags: filenames

I have this function:

```lisp
;; needs work in case of spaces in filenames
(cl-defun filename-from-buffer (&key get-ext get-abs)
  "Returns the absolute name, with or without extension,
   of the file that is open in the current buffer."
  (let ((filename (buffer-name))
        (absname (buffer-file-name)))
    (cond
     ((and get-ext get-abs) absname )
     (get-abs (file-name-sans-extension absname ))
     (get-ext filename)
     (t (file-name-sans-extension filename)))))
```

You can test it with something like this,

```lisp
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-l t")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (insert (filename-from-buffer :get-ext t :get-abs t))
   ;; /Nuskha/With Space/file.ext
   (insert "\n")
   (insert (filename-from-buffer))
   ;; file
   (insert "\n")
   (insert (filename-from-buffer :get-ext t))
   ;; file.ext
   (insert "\n")
   (insert (filename-from-buffer :get-abs t))))
   ;; /Nuskha/With Space/file
```

It works fine, but when there are spaces in the name, as shown in the comments above, the names are not such that you could take them verbatim and use with the `cd` command.

```
$ cd /Nuskha/With Space/file
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I want a function that returns something like this `/Nuskha/With\ Space/file`. How could this be done?

Comment: In Emacs jargon, what you called "path" are called *absolute file names*. A "path" in Emacs jargon is a list like the value of environment variable `$PATH`.

Comment: I see, so the function `pathname` and `absname` work the same? Because right now, I am using `pathname` and it works as in the usual understanding of the word path.

Comment: I don't understand the question in your comment. Where are you seeing a function `pathname` or `absname`?

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I forgot what I was doing there. I thought I was calling a function in `let` instead of assigning variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes to make `cd` think `/Nuskha/With Space/file` is one single argument, not two, e.g.,

```
$ cd "/Nuskha/With Space/file"
$ cd '/Nuskha/With Space/file'
```

You can also use `shell-quote-argument`:

```
(shell-quote-argument "/Nuskha/With Space/file")
;; => "/Nuskha/With\\ Space/file"
```